# How to access members of forward declared class

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'm trying to figure out how to access member variable of forward declared class though pointer.

**My code:**

```
#include <iostream>

class Boo;
class Foo{
public:
    int getNum() {
        return booPtr->num; //Error: Member access into incomplete type 'Boo'
    }
    Boo *booPtr;
};
class Boo : public Foo {
public:
    Boo() {
        booPtr = this;
    }
    int num = 45;
};
int main() {
    Boo boo;
    int num = boo.getNum();
    std::cout <<  num << '\n';
}
```

**The error I get :**

> "return booPtr->num" : Member access into incomplete type 'Boo'

**The result I expect :**

```
45
```

How can I fix this error and what would be more common and safer way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the member function `getNum()` where the type `Boo` is known to the compiler. Hence change the class definition of `Foo` to

```
class Boo;

class Foo{
  public:
    int getNum();

    Boo *booPtr;
};
```

Then comes the definition of `Boo`, and finally

```
int Foo::getNum()
{
    return booPtr->num;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When you access members of a class, the class has to be complete type; only forward declaration is not enough.

You can move the definition of the member function out of the class definition and after the definition of `Boo`.

```
class Boo;
class Foo{
public:
    int getNum();
    Boo *booPtr;
};
class Boo : public Foo {
    ...
};

int Foo::getNum() {
    return booPtr->num;
}
```